# Is there a function which grows faster than any slowly varying function but slower than any power of x?

Tags: probability-theory, slowly-varying-functions

I was thinking about if there are random variables lying in between different domains of attractions. And in short, it seems to me, that this latter question boils down to: is there a function which grows faster than any slowly varying function, but slower than any power of $x$?

Comment: What's the definition of a slowly varying function?

Comment: Adam, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function
A measurable function L is called slowly varying (at infinity) if for all $a > 0$:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{L(a x)}{L(x)}= 1.$$

Comment: That definition would be better off in the question body. I've never heard of slowly varying functions either.